# How do i consume .net webservice with java eclipse genymade

Tags: service

im have created a webservice with .net and it is running perfectly fine,now i have to develop an  application on another platform which is java(eclipse,genymade)which call the web service that i have created in .net im not sure how to get started,can someone help me on this,or probably can share some article with me.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want an article this is probably what you want? [Consuming web service in java](http://www.eliotdill.com/2009/06/web-service-client/).
Anyway it also depends on what kind of data format you are gonna parse. it may be either JSON or XML..

Comment: do u mind assisting me...im currently refering to the article u given me...but im stuck at step 3 im not able to see  tree option under my project entitled Source Packages,wat im having only default package,y is it so?